# run compact dishwasher drain pipe into kitchen sink

Tags: installation, dishwasher

Amazingly I could not find any information about this on the internet!!!

I am renting a flat and the only option I have if I want a dishwasher is to buy a tabletop/compact dishwasher. Because of the layout of the kitchen, the only option I would have is to run the drainpipe into the kitchen sink...i.e.not connected below the sink to the trap, but just running the drain into the main sink from above the work surface where the dishwasher would be placed. Is this feasable? Would I need to make the drain pipe go up and then down or could i run it horizontal along the worktop and then down into the sink fr it to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the high loop or air gap in dishwasher drains when installed below the counter are because of the risk of drain water being pushed back into the dishwasher. If you have a clog in the sink and don't have that high loop, water can drain into the dishwasher and flood out your kitchen. So with a countertop dishwasher, I don't see the need for the high loop since the drain hose is already above the level of the countertop.

Comment: I would add that the drain should not be ran into the sink and placed at the edge. There's a matter of the dishwasher siphoning the water back in as well which would be possible if the drain backed up filling the sink above the end of the drain line.

Comment: Hey,thanks so much. So I can just run the drain pipe horizontally from the tabletop dishwasher and then curl it down into the kitchen sink basin and it should work ok ?

Comment: Follow the instructions that come with it, but don't see why you couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's common enough. Were you planning to hard-plumb the dishwasher? They sell the adapter in the photo, plus a new aerator for the faucet. One pipe is for hot water the other pipe is the drain.

You clip and unclip it from the faucet as needed. The red button is to relieve the pressure and for you to take some water from it while it's running.

[image: portable dishwasher faucet adaptor]

Comment: Ah, no... I am going to plumb in the water pipe and feed it through to the dishwasher. The sink trap does nit have an additional connection so I will need to just hang the drain pipe into the kitchen sink. Its not ideal but it should work. I might need a cable tie to hold the drain pipe in place.